# Console Log not Logging -it's at the very beginnng of the js file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

my console log is not outputting anything. It's at the very start of the javascript file, so I have no idea why it doesn't log anything.

Otherwise I'm getting a 302 "Error", but I assume the problem is server side.

Lastly, the ajax post is not getting written into the database. As I've never worked with AJAX before, any pointers would be welcome.

Note: I'm using a Mikrotik as a HotSpot, and it's using $ (dolar signs) for it's own purpuse, so I can't use JQuery.

Thanks for all the help.

This is the whole code, as is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>HotSpot</title>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Hotspot login form -->
    <form name="hotspot" action="$(link-login-only)" method="post" id="hotspot"
        $(if chap-id) onSubmit="return doLogin(); return false;" $(endif)>
        <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="$(link-orig)" />
        <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
        <input type="hidden" name="username" type="text" value="HSuser" />
        <input type="hidden" name="password" type="password" value="SimpleUserPassword" />
    </form>

    <!-- Mail for which gets inserted into the DB -->
    <form name="mail" action="http://some.domain/validate-sanitize.php" method="post" id="mail">
        <h1>Hotspot</h1>
        <h2>To gain internet access, enter your email.</h2>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_ok" name="submit_ok" /> <br />
    </form>

<script rel="javascript"  type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("submit_ok").addEventListener("click", SendAjax);

    function SendAjax() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        console.log(email);
        // Check if fields are empty 
        if (email=="") {
            alert("Please enter your email.");
        }
        // AJAX code to submit form
        else{

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '$(link-login-only)', true);
            xhr.send("dst=$(link-orig)&popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");{
                setTimeout(function(){      
                console.log("Fired " + email);
                document.getElementById("submit_ok").submit();}, 500 );
            }
        }
    }
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should work, but will most likely be "overwritten" because you don't stop the browser from also submitting the form.

Comment: remove the form tags and try.!

Comment: the browser does nothing. it just stays on the page. When i check the database, it remains empty, and laptop doesn't get internet access (it does not get validated). What tags are you refering too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Mikrotik. Login was set as CHAP (password authentication with salt), and this method was not implemented. Still don't know why that would be causeing the console.log problems, but well, there it is.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer you question, still it will show the result.

Try replace `console.log(email);` with `alert(email);`. 
Did you try another browser?

Comment: What is the output of window.console?

Comment: console remains empty, but i get the alert/pop-up

Comment: Put this code before console.log(email):
if (!window.console) {
    alert("Not supported");
} and let me know the output. did you tried another browser?

Comment: I got the response in console.log this time... I haven't tried with another browser yet. need to get admin access (should get it in cca 30 mins)

Comment: How do you get the response? Does it logging now?

Comment: well, now i get nothing back on the console and no alert... it's just wierd. I've been working on this for the past week, and so far i haven't had any problems with the console.

Comment: alert does not solve the problem, as it stops the browser. Read the comment in the question about  `form submit`. This shows a result, but console log is not shown due a timing problem. So alert will not help to understand why console.log does notwork.